# Convert rtf byte array to pdf byte array in C#

Tags: c#, pdf, rtf

I have a program that uses `WebClient` to download a file from a remote server. I am using `DownloadData` rather than `DownloadFile` because I don't really need the physical file. I am just taking the byte array and converting it to a base64 string for submission through an API as part of the payload. For some files, I will download them as RTF, but they need to be converted to a searchable PDF before I send them through the API. I'd rather handle this conversion with just the byte arrays in memory, rather than saving files to disk, then converting. Is there a way for me to take the RTF byte array and convert it to a (searchable) PDF byte array?

I tried just saving the rtf byte array to a pdf, but that does not work. Here's my code for that:
`System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\temp\pdfTest.pdf", fileBytes);`

Comment: rtf != pdf. They have different names because they're completely different formats. What does the API do? rtf is just as searchable as pdf, if not more.

Comment: yes, rtf is certainly searchable, but this particular document is required to be a searchable pdf when submitted to this third-party api. If I have to, I'll perform the file download, then convert to pdf, but I'd like to just keep it in memory if possible.

Comment: Why can't you just convert it to a pdf in memory? Also, I was asking about the API because maybe there's one that operates on rtf?

Comment: You need some software that can parse RTF and emit pdf. Do you have such a library?

Comment: I was thinking of using a pdf printer like cutepdf if I do this with file i/o. I'm not sure if those libraries have functionality for byte arrays, but I suppose they might. I'll research it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The following solution requires a Telerik subscription, but I am using it to convert an rtf byte array to a pdf byte array:

```
byte[] bOutput;
Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Rtf.RtfFormatProvider RTFprovider = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Rtf.RtfFormatProvider();
string strRTF = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bInput);
Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.Model.RadFlowDocument document = RTFprovider.Import(strRTF);
        Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Pdf.PdfFormatProvider PDFprovider = new Telerik.Windows.Documents.Flow.FormatProviders.Pdf.PdfFormatProvider();
        bOutput = PDFprovider.Export(document);
```